# Disabled fullscreen in qt program

Tags: qt, fullscreen

I search to disable F11 keys or ctr+ F11 who put my program qt in fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

In Design mode change QWidget minimumSize and maximumSize parameters to equal value (bottom right corner of Qt creator).

For example: for minimumSize width = 400, height = 250; for maximumSize equal values width = 400, height = 250. You can see it on a screenshot:

example of values for necessary parameters

[image]